# How to make consistent color scales between two plots with geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, hexagonal-tiles

I'm trying to make a before/after comparison between two plots, so I need them to both have the same color scale so a true comparison can be made. I have been trying for a while to change the color scales of geom_hex, but I have only find ways of providing a min/max cut off. Is there anyway of manually setting the scale to be a defined range, e.g. 1-100? My plot code and examples are below.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_hex(aes(x=VolumeBefore$Flow, y=SpeedBefore$Speed)) +
  xlab("Flow") + ylab("Speed (MPH)")+
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0), text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  ggtitle('Speed-Flow Before Density Plot')

ggplot() +
  geom_hex(aes(x=VolumeAfter$Flow, y=SpeedAfter$Speed)) +
  xlab("Flow") + ylab("Speed (MPH)")+
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0), text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  ggtitle('Speed-Flow After Density Plot')
```

[Before Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW9Ro.png)

[After Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MZnh.png)

In these two images you can see the scales are different, I just want to make them the same :)
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by max/min, but setting `limits = c(1,100)` in `scale_fill_continuous()` ought to accomplish what you describe. (Side note: never, ever refer to variables inside of `aes()` with `$`; always do `ggplot(data = VolumeBefore),aes(x = Flow,y = Speed)`.)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the info @joran that's good to know!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using `scale_fill_gradient2` and `oob = scales::squish`, which lets you specify the lower and upper range for the fill, and constrains any values beyond that range.

Note that without specifications, the fill will use the full range of densities in the data:

```
ggplot(diamonds) +
  geom_hex(aes(x=carat,y=price)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2()
```

[image]

We could alternately specify the range directly, clamping anything beyond into that range. That will let you match multiple plots' legend ranges:

```
ggplot(diamonds) +
  geom_hex(aes(x=carat,y=price)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(limits = c(0, 3000), oob = scales::squish)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome that was exactly what I needed, It worked perfectly!

Comment: You can do the same with just `scale_fill_continuous`.